# QGIS incoming interaction from web application (web browser)

Tags: qgis, wfs, url

Is there a way to instruct QGIS to open and center WFS layer on given feature?

Can we use a link with custom protocol:

`<a href="qgis://wfs-layer-address?with=parameters-to-center-and-zoom-give-feature">Open feature in Qgis</a>`

Is there any support in QGIS to handle such or similar links? Will it open new layer every time, or it will be smart enough to center already opened layer  (opening many features one after another) ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: @PolyGeo done. Question was reedited and minimized.

Comment: At the moment you still have three questions (from a count of question marks).  At least the middle one seems to be superfluous so I think you should simply delete it.  Have you researched/tried doing this prior to posting here?

Comment: Those "3 questions" are about the same solution, they are there to encourage people to elaborate a little bit more on the topic. More over last two questions does not make sense on their own if the first one will get negative answer. I have a feeling that that the question in this form is acceptable. I might be wrong though. Thank you for comments and help with improving the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to communicate from a web browser to a currently running QGIS then you will have to do a bit of work. All you can do from a web browser is run a program via the same mechanism that starts a PDF browser when you click a PDF link - the returned mime-type of the file is mapped to an application and that application starts with a filename.

This means for QGIS it will start a fresh QGIS every time, which is not what you want.

You may have to write a script, let's call it qgis-driver, that is mapped to mime-types in your browser. Then when someone clicks on something you want communicated to a running qgis, it runs qgis-driver. Then on your running QGIS you have a plugin that is either checking for messages from qgis-driver via a timer (every few seconds?). The qgis-driver can then the running tell QGIS what to do (load this layer, replacing any existing layer, set the extent, etc etc). There are plugins that do [this sort of thing](https://websvn.tuxfamily.org/filedetails.php?repname=tuxgis%2Fgeotux&path=%2Ftrunk%2FSyncQGISWithDir%2Fsyncqgiswithdir.py).

You'd need to figure out a communication protocol between qgis-driver and QGIS, and consider security (to stop *anyone* controlling your QGIS over the network or locally on a multi-user machine).

Some applications do have this sort of remote control built in - for example if you run firefox twice then (with the right options) the second time it will just open a new window rather than starting a new firefox process. QGIS doesn't have this, so you'd have to implement something like it.

Comment: Thx for the idea. So if it requires to write a plugin for Qgis I might skip communication with the browser and communicate directly with the server. Do pooling or use websockets. Anyway thank you for the link to the plugin that do work periodically,